# How to return rest of line after a searched-for string in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

Using ActiveState perl 5.8 on windows. I am placing the results of `sc qc MyServiceName` into a variable.

```
$MSSQLResults=`sc qc $MSSQLServiceName`;
print "MSSQLResults $MSSQLResults";
```

If I print the variable to STDOUT I get something like:

```
[SC] QueryServiceConfig SUCCESS
SERVICE_NAME: MSSQL$INSTANCE1
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS 
        START_TYPE         : 3   DEMAND_START
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.INSTANCE1\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe" -sINSTANCE1
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   : 
        TAG                : 0
        DISPLAY_NAME       : SQL Server (INSTANCE1)
        DEPENDENCIES       : 
        SERVICE_START_NAME : TESTLAB\svc_SQLServer
```

The string I want returned from a grep or regex match is `TESTLAB\svc_SQLServer`
. Should I use grep, or regex, or something else? What line of perl would accomplish what I want? The text `TESTLAB\svc_SQLServer` will vary depending on which machine I run it on.

Comment: -1 So you want whatever is after `SERVICE_START_NAME : `? You should make this clear instead of having us guessing.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a scalar variable (e.g `$MSSQLResults`) which you want to search. In that case:

```
if (my ($service_start_name) = $MSSQLResults=~ m/SERVICE_START_NAME\s+:\s+(.*)/m) {
    # do something
}
```

Comment: I just want to put the results of the regex search into another variable. So in this case the "other variable" would have `TESTLAB\svc_SQLServer` as a string

Comment: @MooMinTroll the answer already provides that functionality. Put it in a subroutine and profit.